# $scope.$emit with partials

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

My *domain.tld/login* is a partial (*login.html*) included within the index.html.

*index.html* also `ng-include`'s a partial that is visible based on `ng-if` attribute.

The idea is to evaluate `ng-if` condition to true once a user has authenticated.

To achieve that I wanted to `$scope.$emit` from `LoginCtrl`, whose scope *is* (**seems to be**) a child of the `IndexCtrl`'s scope.

The problem is: `LoginCtrl`' doesn't get loaded/executed. It's route:

```
.when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })
```

The contents of `LoginCtrl` are as follows:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope) {
        console.log("LoginCtrl");
        $scope.$emit('authEvent');
    });
```

The listener for the `$scope.$emit` even in `IndexCtrl` is:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('IndexCtrl', function ($scope) {
    console.log("IndexCtrl");
        $scope.$on('authEvent', function(event) {
            console.log("Emit received");
            $scope.authenticated = "true";
        });
    });
```

*"LoginCtrl"* message never gets logged to the console. At the load of *domain.tld/login* page only *"IndexCtrl"* gets logged. After clicking the "Login" button, and proceeding to the *domain.tld/users* page, the following is logged to the console:

```
IndexCtrl index.js:14
UserStatsCtrl users.js:24
Emit received
```

*index.html* simplified:

```
<body data-ng-controller="IndexCtrl">

    <aside ng-if="authenticated" id="left-panel" ng-cloak>
        <span ng-include="'left-panel.html'"></span></aside>

    <div id="content" data-ng-view="" class="view-animate"></div>

</body>
```

A dummy`$scope.$emit` event gets emitted from controllers of the partials that follow the /login page,e.g., *domain.tld/users*. However I would like to have all business of the authentication to be done within the `LoginCtrl`, before any of the further partials would be accessible/presented to a user.

Thank you.

### UPDATE:

I had a `<script>` snippet directly within the *login.html* partial; to validate user-supplied data for the input fields. When this `<script>` is commented out, the controller works, and the following is logged to the console:

```
IndexCtrl index.js:14
LoginCtrl login.js:12
Emit received index.js:16
```

`<script>`'s contents will now become part of the `LoginCtrl`.

Gracias and Entschuldigung.